What is the difference between two methods of calculating irreversible work in finite-time thermodynamics?
In finite-time thermodynamics, there are two methods for calculating irreversible work, derived from two different papers:

Method 1 (from doi: 10.1103/PhysRevE.104.034117):

Excess work: Work under general conditions minus work under equilibrium conditions
$$ \begin{aligned}W_{ex}&=-\int pdV+\int p_{eq}dV\\&=-\int(p-p_{eq})dV\end{aligned} $$
Since
$$ p=\frac{nRT}{V},\;P_{eq}=\frac{nRT_{b}}{V} $$
We have
$$ \begin{aligned}
W_{ex}& =-\int(\frac{nRT}{V}-\frac{nRT_b}{V})dV  \\
&=\int_{V_{0}}^{V_{\tau}}-nR(T(t)-T_b)\frac{1}{V(t)}dV(t) \\
\end{aligned} $$

Method 2 (from doi: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.210601):

$$ \Delta S^{(\mathrm{ir})}=\int_0^\tau\left(\frac{\dot{Q}}{T}+\frac{\dot{Q}_b}{T_b}\right)dt, $$
Where: $\dot{Q}=-\dot{Q}_b=\delta Q/dt$ represents heat flow from the heat bath to the system
$$ \delta Q=-\kappa[T(t)-T_{b}]dt $$
$$ \Delta S^{(\mathrm{ir})}=\int_{0}^{\tau}\kappa\frac{[T(t)-T_{b}]^{2}}{T(t)T_{b}}dt. $$
$$ W_{\mathrm{Th}}^{(\mathrm{ir})}=T_{b}\Delta S^{(\mathrm{ir})} $$
Specific analysis:
We need to verify if
$$ -nR(T-T_{b})\frac{\dot{V}}{V}=T_{b}\kappa\frac{(T-T_{b})^{2}}{TT_{b}} $$
Simplifying, we get
$$ -nR\frac{\dot{V}}{V}=\frac{\kappa(T-T_{b})}{T} $$
Since we have
$$ nR=\frac{PV}{T},\kappa(T-T_{b})=-\frac{\delta Q}{dt} $$
Therefore
$$ -\frac{PV}{T}\frac{\dot{V}}{V}=-\frac{\delta Q}{dt}\frac{1}{T} \quad \Rightarrow  \quad PdV=dQ $$
In the actual process, since temperature changes with time, $dU$ should not equal zero. So are these two methods not equivalent?

Calculation process:

If volume changes according to the exponential strategy $s=t/\tau$, where $\tau$ is the relaxation time:
$$ \tilde{V}_{\mathrm{op}}(s)=V_{0}(V_{f}/V_{0})^{s} $$
Temperature changes according to:
$$ \frac{dT}{dt}=-\frac{nRT}{C_V}\frac{1}{V}\frac{dV}{dt}-\kappa(T-T_\mathrm{b})/C_V, $$
The specific calculation process:

Set initial parameters, e.g., $\tau=2s$, $V_0=0.01 m^3$, $V_f=0.03m^3$, $\kappa=100 W/K$
Given a volume change protocol as in the equation above, substitute into the temperature equation to solve for temperature change over time.
Substitute into the equations for $W_{ex}$ and $W_{\mathrm{Th}}^{(\mathrm{ir})}$ to calculate irreversible work using both methods.

Additional information:
Initial condition: $T_0 = T_b$

Derivation of T(t):

According to the first law of thermodynamics:
$$ dU=dQ-PdV  \quad \Rightarrow \quad  \frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{dQ}{dt}- P\frac{dV}{dt} $$
Also,
$$ U=\frac{3}{2}nRT   \quad \Rightarrow \quad   \frac{dU}{dt}= \frac{3}{2}nR\frac{dT}{dt}  $$
Therefore,
$$ \frac{3}{2}nR\frac{dT}{dt}=\kappa(T_{b}-T)-P\frac{dV}{dt} $$
Using $P=\frac{nRT}{V},C_{V}=\frac{3}{2}nR$
$$ \frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{\kappa}{C_V}(T_{b}-T)-\frac{nRT}{V\cdot C_V}\frac{dV}{dt} $$
The calculation results from the first method are always higher. Why is this the case?
The second method seems more general. Is it possible to modify the first method to make the final results more similar?

Symbol explanations:


$T$: System temperature
$T_b$: Heat bath temperature
$V$: Volume
$p$: Pressure
$n$: Amount of substance (in moles)
$R$: Gas constant
$\kappa$: Heat conduction coefficient
$C_V$: Heat capacity at constant volume
$\tau$: Relaxation time

A Mathematica simulation code is provided to compare the two methods numerically. The code sets up the system parameters, defines the optimal volume change protocol, solves for temperature evolution, and calculates the irreversible work using both methods. The results are then plotted for comparison.

Code

Clear["Global`"]
(* Set parameters *)
r = 8.314;  (* Gas constant, J/(mol*K) *)
n = 1;      (* Number of moles *)
tB = 500;   (* Environment temperature, K *)
v0 = 0.03;  (* Initial volume, m^3 *)
vF = 0.01;  (* Final volume, m^3 *)
cv = 3/2*r; (* Heat capacity at constant volume for monoatomic ideal gas *)
(* Additional parameters *)
kappa = 100; (* Heat transfer coefficient, adjust as needed *)
τ = 2;       (* Set τ = 2 *)
numPoints = 200;

(* Define optimal volume change protocol *)
Vopt[t_] := v0*(vF/v0)^(t/τ);
VoptPrime[t_] := D[Vopt[t], t];

(* Solve for temperature evolution *)
TsolExp = 
  Module[{sol}, 
   sol = NDSolve[{T'[t] == -(n r T[t])/(cv Vopt[t]) VoptPrime[t] - 
        kappa*(T[t] - tB)/cv, T[0] == tB}, T, {t, 0, τ}];
   T /. sol[[1]]];

(* Calculate excess work *)
WexExp[t_] := 
  NIntegrate[-n r (TsolExp[s] - tB)/Vopt[s]*VoptPrime[s], {s, 0, t}];

(* Generate data points *)
tList = Table[t, {t, 0, τ, τ/(numPoints)}];
dataWexExp = Table[{t, WexExp[t]}, {t, tList}];

sIrr[t_] := 
  NIntegrate[kappa*(TsolExp[s] - tB)^2/(TsolExp[s]*tB), {s, 0, t}];
Wex = Table[{t, sIrr[t]*tB}, {t, 0, τ, τ/numPoints}];

ListLinePlot[{dataWexExp, Wex}, PlotLegends -> {"WexV", "WexS"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "Wex"}, PlotRange -> All]




Further consideration

Upon further reflection regarding the applicability of the ideal gas equation of state to irreversible processes, I'd like to offer some additional insights:
In the original model, it appears that the authors considered near-equilibrium scenarios for both methods. Each approach necessitates deriving the temperature-time relationship T(t), which is subsequently used in their respective formulas to compute irreversible work. Notably, both methods employed the ideal gas equation of state in their calculations of T(t).
This raises two  questions:

Do both methods implicitly assume the validity of the ideal gas equation of state throughout the process?
Could the use of the ideal gas equation of state be the primary factor contributing to the discrepancy in irreversible work calculations between these two methods?


Your are missing the plots. However, this question shows a lot of work and care and so take my upvote.

What does the subscript b stand for?

In the original model, it's a cylinder-piston system immersed in a constant-temperature water bath, so 'b' stands for the water bath.

Do you think that during an irreversible expansion, the ideal gas law describes the pressure of the gas on the piston?

I think there may be an issue of differing definitions for the same phrase "excess work". In the end work is always just $\int {\bf f} \cdot d{\bf x}$ for some force $\bf f$ and displacement $\bf x$. So as long as you keep clear which system is doing the work (and also what is the process you are comparing with if you are calculating an "excess") then any work calculation should be unambiguous and does not require concepts such as entropy and heat.

P.S. comment by Chet Miller is also correct: one cannot assume an equilibrium equation of state is obeyed during a non-quasistatic process.

In both methods mentioned above, the numerical solution of T(t) is used. However, in the process of solving for the numerical solution of T(t), the ideal gas equation of state was used. So it seems that both methods employed the ideal gas equation of state. Perhaps the discrepancy doesn't stem from this aspect.

In an irreversible process, the ideal gas law is not satisfied by the gas in the cylinder.

See the following thread (the later posts in the thread):  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/moving-an-adiabatic-partition-in-an-adiabatic-container.981529/
